# I want the command prompt to be invisiblewhile it is working

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

When i run the bat file the command prompt appears even if i use `@echo off` some commands' prompts are visible so i need to make command prompt invisible while it is working

Comment: If you don't want to minimize it, then you'll need to run it from another program, scrip or utility which offers a hidden window option. You could do that by running your batch file using VBScript, a dedicated utility, or depending upon your needs from Task Scheduler or even as a Windows service.

Comment: In any command that you don't want to appear in the terminal window, you can add `>nul 1>&2` at the end of the line.
This does not hide the window, but prevents output from being displayed in the window.

Answer (score 0):

Put `>nul` at the end of the sentence.

for Example:

```
copy example1.txt example2.txt >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it create a VSBScript and write

```
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c C:\YourPath\YourFile.bat"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```